# Having confusion in this how can I solve

Tags: summation

An ellipse is drawn with major axis and minor axis of lengths 10 and 8 respectively. Using one focus as the centre,a circle is drawn that is tangent to the ellipse,with no part being outside the ellipse. Then the radius of the circle is:
Ans : Radius = 2 HOW???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 
$$a = \frac{10}{2} = 5, b = \frac{8}{2} = 4$$
Then, to find the focii
$$c^2 = a^2 - b^2 = 25 - 16 = 9$$
So that $c = 3$. Therefore if we want to draw a circle tangent to the ellipse, with no part being outside the ellipse we still have 2 units inside the ellipse (since $a - c = 5 - 3 = 2$). Hence using one focus as the center, a circle is drawn that is tangent to the ellipse, with no part being outside the ellipse.